# filter a column using spark databricks dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe, and I have a column called `url`, what I want is to select all the url which is not containing the word `"www.ebay.com"`, I have tried this:

```
%python
display(flutten_df.printSchema())
display(flutten_df[flutten_df['url'].str.contains("www.ebay.com")])
```

it gives me this error:

> AnalysisException: Can't extract value from url#75009: need struct
> type but got string;

the schema is :

```
root
|-- web: string (nullable = true)
|-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

How to fix this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use pandas syntax on spark DataFrame.

In Pyspark, `flutten_df['url'].str` means *get struct field `str` from column `url`*. Thus you got that error saying it can't extract value from a column which is not a struct.

Use `filter` with `rlike` instead:

```py
display(flutten_df.filter(~flutten_df['url'].rlike("www.ebay.com")))
```